# Add a scheduled task at the setup?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, scheduled-tasks

I've a little c# application, and I have to create a scheduled task for this application.

I have a Setup which installs the application, and the best case will be that I can set this windows scheduled task at the installation.

Any idea if it's possible and/or how?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) on codeplex - this can be used to create a small console application that will setup a task and can be run by your installer.

You can also run the [`schtasks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx) command line utility for a similar result.

Comment: Will the console application be visible? How can I add tasks?

Comment: @J4N - Yes, it normally would be, until the process finishes. How to add? I suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: I just don't know how this is called, is this "PostBuildEvent"?

Comment: "PostBuildEvent" is a visual studio option that will execute after teh build has finished. Nothing to do with installers. As for adding tasks to the task scheduler, read the documentation in the links.#

Comment: I took a look, but I can't find a good documentation for the default visual studio installer. i found these "Custom Actions", is it this?

Comment: @J4N You can prevent the console application window from being shown by setting attributes in process startup structure.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a whole answer, but depending on the installer (for example I think wise does it) you can setup tasks from there. Otherwise, you could call your app with a special commandline parameter to do so and utilise the api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614.aspx as a possibility