# How to make a scheduled task run directly after install instead of having to start the installed application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, scheduled-tasks

The question may not be specific to scheduled tasks, it's just that it's what I'm trying to do.

As the title implies, I want the start the application (which adds a scheduled task) automatically after the installation. I'm searching for the simplest solution if possible. I read about Custom Actions, but I'm not sure that it's what I am aiming for.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6678781/806549) will help?

Comment: @AndersUP Well I indeed used this wrapper to make my trigger/scheduler, but after installation, the task is not scheduled automatically. I have to start the .exe that has been installed in order for the task to be properly scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Custom actions are the only support from Windows Installer that you can use to launch your application directly after the application has ended. You need a simple custom action to launch your EXE, aat the end of the InstallExecute Sequence, scheduled as deferred (i.e. after all files have been installed), NOT immediate.